# Is SQL Server Management Studio capable of managing SQL Server 2000 databases?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

I know this is really basic, but I can't find the answer in Google or SF, so I thought I'd better just ask.

If I run SQL Server 2008 R2 Management Studio on my PC, can I manage a SQL Server 2000 database server?

I know I can do it from SQL Server 2008 (non-R2) Management Studio, though I need a legacy component to manage Data Transformation Services.  I can cope fine without that component - all my DTS has been migrated to SSIS on a SQL 2005 / 2008 Servers, but I still have a legacy 2000 server and I'd like to be able to admin everything from one console.

Comment: Are you sure you are running SQL Server 2010 Management Studio? It seems not exists on Microsoft site. Or do you have this: http://www.sqlmanager.net/en/products/studio/mssql

Comment: Apologies, I meant 2008 R2, not 2010.  Have edited.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes it can connect to a SQL Server 2000 instance. You do lose some functionality like the activity monitor so depending on your daily needs in terms of database monitoring you may need to have multiple version of the management studio installed.

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure that it can connect to a SQL 2000 server.